# how to get data from another table using user_id

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

As a user, i want to view my profile when i logged in. The data i want to view is from another table using user_id.

I've tried the code below but instead I get all the data of the table. I've tried using session_id but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <table style="border: 2px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <th>Users Id</th>
            <th>Language from</th>
            <th>Language to</th>
            <th>Category name</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Number of words of file</th>
            <th>Count of words paste</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        //$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from checkout JOIN users WHERE users.user_id = checkout.user_id");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['language_from']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['language_to']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['file']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['file_count']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['word_count']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please try to help me, guys...

Comment: use a `WHERE` clause using the user id

Comment: `WHERE users.user_id = checkout.user_id` i've tried it but it has a the same output

Comment: use this `WHERE users.user_id = checkout.user_id AND users.user_id = $user_id` `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: you've tried using inner join?

Comment: no sir...i haven't use inner join

Comment: @PathikVejani i've use your code but it doesn't work either sir T__T

Comment: what is the value of `$user_id`?

Comment: the id of the user which is from the users table

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, if you already have the user_id just do

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = <your user_id>
```

Or to fix your first request

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN checkout AS c 
ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE u.id = <id>
```

Comment: Then explain us what you've and what you want to retrieve, question is unclear.